# How to access php session variable in another page?

Tags: php, session

I have this shopping cart page coded, but i am clueless about how to acces the product id from session in another page? Anyone please help me! I'm beginner so if you please give me example code too it'd help me a lot.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $product_ids = array();
//session_destroy();

//check if Add to Cart button has been submitted
if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'add_to_cart')){
    if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])){

        //keep track of how mnay products are in the shopping cart
        $count = count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);

        //create sequantial array for matching array keys to products id's
        $product_ids = array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], 'id');

        if (!in_array(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id'), $product_ids)){
        $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$count] = array
            (
                'id' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id'),
                'name' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name'),
                'price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price'),
                'quantity' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantity')
            );   
        }    
    }
    else { //if shopping cart doesn't exist, create first product with array key 0
        //create array using submitted form data, start from key 0 and fill it with values
        $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][0] = array
        (
            'id' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id'),
            'name' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name'),
            'price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price'),
            'quantity' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantity')
        );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: as long as you have `session_start();` on the other page you access the $_SESSION array like any other array

Comment: What other page? Please show the part of code that has problem accessing $_SESSION variable.

Comment: I mean if i want to access the product id from session variable, what will be the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same code you have here on the other page to get the product_ids

```
//other page
session_start();
$product_ids = array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], 'id');
```